# jQuery UI : How can I set the resizing limit, aspect ratio when I increase/decrease the size of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div tag, it is ( div tag ) resizable and inside that I have a h1 tag ( or it would be any tag ).

**The Problem :**

I am having 2 problems :

1. The aspect ratio is not working properly as I want means "when I increase/decrease the size of the div its height gets larger" so how can I set it properly and
2. I want to fix the smallest width on resizing means "if on decreasing the size it reached to 27px it stop decreasing."

**Code**

```
$('.draggable_element').each(function() {
        $(this).resizable({
        autoHide: true,
      handles: 's,e,w',
      aspectRatio: 1/9
    });
})
```

[Here is my jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44ve3syv/)

**UPDATE :**

I think I have not properly explained my first problem to know what's the first problem please visit to my fiddle link try to resize (increase/decrease) the div from left side or right side the height of the div will automatically increase that the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have seen your fiddle. Why you don't just remove `aspectRatio`. It will work better for you as you are expecting.

Please update your resize().

```
$(this).resizable({
  autoHide: true,
  handles: 's,e,w',
  minWidth: 27
});
```

I think you might be looking something like this one

Thought it will helpful

Answer (score 2):

For your 1st problem, you can use `aspectRatio: true`, it will use the initial aspect ratio based on your element's width and height.

For your 2nd problem, you can use `minWidth` option

```
$('.draggable_element').each(function() {
    $(this).resizable({
      autoHide: true,
      handles: 's,e,w',
      aspectRatio: true,
      minWidth: 27
  });
})
```

Comment: OK I get it. I have updated my answer. You can have a look.

Answer (score 2):

1. The aspectRatio should be Boolean. You can set the size using Width and Height.

Alternatively you could also try to change the ratio to '9/1': `aspectRatio: 9/1`, should do the work too...

2. Set 'minWidth: 27'.

   ```
   $(this).resizable({
     autoHide: true,
     handles: 's,e,w',
     aspectRatio: true,
     minWidth: 27
   });
   ```